# What is the hotkey for adding rows in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts

After 1/2 hour of googling to no avail, I am ready to ask this here: As the title says, what is the *hotkey* for adding/removing rows in an already existing table in Google *Docs*?

It seems excessively tedious to just keep going through the menu and adding rows one by one.

Comment: Dear readers: Please note that this question is about Google Docs (a text processor, similar to Microsoft Word), not about Google Sheets (a spreadsheet app, similar to Microsoft Excel). If you are looking a Q/A about the last question checkout [Shortcut to insert new row in Google Spreadsheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/44607/88163)

Answer (score 27):

Pressing Tab when the cursor is at the rightmost of the bottom row automatically adds a new row below it. It's quite handy if you don't know how many rows you need in advance and require them as you type along.

Pressing the Tab key at the LAST CELL of a row, for those working in a table

Comment: I appreciate you!

Answer (score 7):

**if you are with Chrome browser:**

- press <kbd>**<kbd>LEFTALT</kbd>** + **<kbd>O</kbd>**</kbd> + **<kbd>2</kbd>** + **<kbd>B</kbd>** for adding row **below**
- or press <kbd>**<kbd>LEFTALT</kbd>** + **<kbd>O</kbd>**</kbd> + **<kbd>2</kbd>** + **<kbd>A</kbd>** for adding row  **above**
- press <kbd>**<kbd>LEFTALT</kbd>** + **<kbd>O</kbd>**</kbd> + **<kbd>2</kbd>** + **<kbd>E</kbd>** for **deleting** a row

**if you are with an alternative browser:**

- press <kbd>**<kbd>LEFTALT</kbd>** + **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** + **<kbd>O</kbd>**</kbd> + **<kbd>2</kbd>** + **<kbd>B</kbd>** for adding row **below**
- or press <kbd>**<kbd>LEFTALT</kbd>** + **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** + **<kbd>O</kbd>**</kbd> + **<kbd>2</kbd>** + **<kbd>A</kbd>** for adding row **above**
- press <kbd>**<kbd>LEFTALT</kbd>** + **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** + **<kbd>O</kbd>**</kbd> + **<kbd>2</kbd>** + **<kbd>E</kbd>** for **deleting** a row

---

**NOTE:**  **<kbd>2</kbd>** not  **<kbd>NUM2</kbd>**

Comment: Usually  a `+` is used to say that the keys should be pressed at the same time. I don't know if there a standard notation to use for keyboard pressing steps, but maybe a comma as it means pause, could be better than `+` On the first bullet, left alt and O keys should be pressed simultaneously, but once the Format  menu is open then they could be released.

Comment: @Rubén agreed, but it works even if pressed like presented

Comment: I'm sorry if appeared that I was saying that the key sequences doesn't work, that was not my intention. Do you see yourself pressing five keys at the same time to insert a row? I don't see myself doing that :)

Answer (score 5):

You can add a new row once (from the menu), then repeat the action by pressing <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: That works but is the most non-standard implementation of "redo" that I've ever seen; it usually only operates on commands that you've undone.

Answer (score 3):

## Short answer

<strike>There isn't</strike> Summary of [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/119555/88163): Use <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to open the Format menu, then the keys shown underlined or parenthesis enclosed.

## Explanation

Keyboard shortcuts are shown in menus, contextual menus and by (on Windows) pressing <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd></kbd>

The above doesn't show a keyboard shortcut to insert rows on Google Docs documents but there is a keyboard sequence that could be used to do that. Just look to the menu for underlined letters or keys shown parenthesis enclosed.

## Suggested action

Send feedback to Google

Comment: Wow, ok. Fail on googles part! ><

Answer (score 1):

Right click and select 'insert row below'. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> to add multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

Click on the table and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome it's Alt + I, R, arrow up/down to insert new row above or below.

Answer (score -1):

Google Sheets's native way of doing this requires a lot of keystrokes as described elsewhere, but you can now easily record a macro doing the action, in this case inserting a row (Under Extensions->Macros) and assign it a single key command (and modify the source as needed).

Here is what my modified macro (to insert multiple rows) looks like:

```
function myFunction1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var numRows = spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsAfter(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getLastRow(), numRows);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(numRows, 0, numRows, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
};
```

Since this is also likely relevant to people finding this, here is the (unmodified) macro to delete rows:

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().deleteRows(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows());
};
```

Comment: This question is about Google Docs not about Google Sheets.